# asynchronous blocks giving NULL

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, block

When I've set a breakpoint to the first for loop, I've noticed that it's being executed but the value is not being updated to the string "Viki". Instead it's just being NULL.

Also, the last line of code `NSLog(@"Mahal");` is not executed. Why?

```
 NSMutableArray *arr1;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        [arr1 addObject:@"Viki"]; 
    }

    NSLog(@"Hello");
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                   NSLog(@"Taj");
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", [arr1 objectAtIndex:i]);
        }
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 2
            NSLog(@"Mahal"); // 3
        });
    });
```

Comment: Replace first line of the code with this:

NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: @BabuLal Also, the last line NSLog(@"Mahal"); is not being executed. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: You should use dispatch_async instead of dispatch_sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize `arr1` to point to an actual array object. You've only declared the pointer variable, you've never made it point to anything. It defaults to `nil` and all messages to `nil` return `nil` (or other zero-valued result appropriate for the type).

You could have discovered this had you ever logged the value of `arr1`.

Comment: I've logged the value of arr1 using breakpoint, However I couldn't recognize the flaw.
Thanks!

Comment: However, the last one `NSLog(@"Mahal");` is not being executed. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: If the code you showed is being run from the main thread, you have created a deadlock. The main thread is running your code and calls `dispatch_sync()`. `dispatch_sync()` will wait until the task it dispatches has run to completion. This prevents the main thread from doing anything. The task you have submitted eventually calls `dispatch_sync()` to submit another task to the main queue, which is serviced by the main thread. That call also waits until the task has run to completion, but that can't even get started because the main thread is waiting for the first task.

Comment: 1. How do I know if my shown code is running from the main thread?
2. Okay, I understood partially. So what would be the work around?

Comment: You need to avoid creating a deadlock situation. How you do that depends on why you're submitting things to concurrent queues or the main queue and why you're using synchronous dispatch routines rather than asynchronous ones and whether you really need to. There's no one-size-fits-all, you-don't-have-to-really-think-about-it answer.